# insert a jquery function to a page in yii

Tags: php, jquery, yii

i have to use a jquery function in yii. i have a code like that and add it in view page.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(function() {
    jQuery( "#item" ).draggable();
    jQuery( "#droppable" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        var $self = jQuery(this);
        var dropOffset = $self.offset();
        var itemOffset = ui.offset;
        var itemRelativePosition = { left: (itemOffset.left - dropOffset.left), top: (itemOffset.top - dropOffset.top) };
        console.log(itemRelativePosition);
        jQuery('#layout').val( '{ left: '+itemRelativePosition.left+', top: '+itemRelativePosition.top+'}' );
      }
    });
   });
   </script>
```

but i cant know why it does not work.is there any other trick to use this code.

Comment: have you already included the jquery library in your view ?

Comment: how do you render this view file, render() or renderPartial()?

Comment: i have include in the main.php

Comment: @user1129286 what happens when the page renders ? any error messages ? can you include the HTML thats output ?

Comment: Start your investigation from installation of [FireBug](https://getfirebug.com/). It is the only trick you should use to avoid a lot of problems like this. There aren't problems in Yii.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register the jquery code

```
<?php
// Javascript 

Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('register_script_name', "
    var partner_only = '".CHTML::activeId($model,'partner_only')."';
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery( '#item' ).draggable();
        jQuery( '#droppable' ).droppable({
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                var $self = jQuery(this);
                var dropOffset = $self.offset();
                var itemOffset = ui.offset;
                var itemRelativePosition = { 
                    left: (itemOffset.left - dropOffset.left), top: (itemOffset.top - dropOffset.top) 
                };
                console.log(itemRelativePosition);
                jQuery('#layout').val( '{ left: '+itemRelativePosition.left+', top: '+itemRelativePosition.top+'}' );
            }
        });
    });
", CClientScript::POS_READY);

?>
```

Hope this answers your question

Answer (score 0):

Add next code to your view file:

```
Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerScriptFile('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js');
Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerScriptFile('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js');
```